# Excel 2007 tab name change

Tags: excel

i want change workbook tab names with first 6 character of cell A1

sheet1 cell A1  248450 Footage 16-12-2013 - TO - 18-12-2013

sheet2 cell A1  254278 Footage 16-12-2013 - TO - 18-12-2013

sheet3 cell A1  248789 FOOTAGE FROM 16-12-2013 - TO - 18-12-2013

sheet4 cell A1  248125 FOOTAGE FROM 16-12-2013 - TO - 18-12-2013

tab name change like below

sheet1 name 248450

sheet2 name 254278

sheet3 name 248789

sheet4 name 248125

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Sub Macro1()
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = Left(A1,6)
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = Left(A1,6)
Sheets("Sheet3").Name = Left(A1,6)
Sheets("Sheet4").Name = Left(A1,6)
End Sub
```

Comment: plz write complete vb scrip

Comment: You have to add one more to each sheet